Oracle APEX - Create 'Duplicate' Button Next to the Report
I have created the apex report where viewers can see the summary of their entries. Each entry can be edited with a simple click on 'edit' button. I managed to create this section. Is there a way to create something similar but as 'duplicate' so the users will be able to duplicate their previous entries / reports?
Thank you


Are you looking for something like this ?

How about interactive grid instead of report, as its built-in menu lets you duplicate rows?

@Littlefoot I use interactive grid - how and where can I find duplicate dynamic function?

You asked where's built-in duplicate row option; here it is, in every row's hamburger menu:

